# Are article-specific meta tags still a part of Open Graph?

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, react-helmet

I'm setting up Open Graph and Twitter Card data in React Helmet for a blog I'm building.  The og type will be article, as in:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
```

so that's easy.  But I've also found reference to additional optional tags to add in such as publication date, author, etc.  Examples:

```
<meta property='article:author' content='https://www.facebook.com/YOUR-NAME' />
<meta property='article:publisher' content='https://www.facebook.com/YOUR-PAGE' />
```

(etc)

They seem straightforward enough to use, but I have some questions trying to look up more information.  First, there's absolutely no information about `article` meta tags anywhere in Facebook's documentation.  Second, I can't find a single blog post or outside resource that mentions these tags written in the last two years, and the tags are suspiciously absent from most of the articles I've read about OG.  I've found references in a few third-part resources like [this](https://ogp.me/) but I can't tell how current that page or any like it are.

Are article meta tags still a thing or are they deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell.

Some are certainly still used for [news indexing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/news-indexing/getting-started), but they have deviated from the [ogp documentation](https://ogp.me/#type_article) with tags like `opinion` and `content_tier`.

The [older tags](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/06/19/platform-updates--new-open-graph-tags-for-media-publishers-and-more/) which have been recommended in the past are not mentioned in the documentation anymore. I don't know if it means they are deprecated or it's just bad documentation.

I think keeping them inside our HTML until it's clear what's happened to them is the way to go. The worst thing that can happen is that they don't affect anything anymore and those 5 extra lines of meta tags barely add any size to our HTML anyway.